# $P(A\cup B\cup C)$ when $C$ is a subset of $B$

Tags: probability

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

> Calculate $P(A\cup B\cup C)$, where $P(A) = 0.2$, $P(B) = 0.5$ and $P(C) = 0.1$.

$A$ and $B$ are independent.
$A$ and $C$ are independent.
$C$ is a subset of $B$.

Formula Union of three events:
$$P(A\cup B\cup C) = P(A) + P(B) + P(C) - P(A\cap B) - P(A\cap C) - P(C\cap B) + P(A\cap B\cap C)$$

$P(A\cap B) = 0.2 \cdot 0.5 = 0.1$

$P(A\cap C) = 0.2 \cdot 0.1 = 0.02$

$P(C\cap B) = P(C)$ because $C$ is a subset of $B$ meaning all of $C$ exists in $B$.

$$P(A\cup B\cup C) = 0.2 + 0.5 + 0.1 - 0.1 - 0.02 - 0.1 + (0.2 \cdot 0.5 \cdot 0.1) = 0.59$$

But this is not correct..

Grateful for any help!

Comment: There should not be a bracket for $-0.1-0.02-0.1$.

Comment: Corrected, but answer is still not correct.

Comment: What is the correct answer?

Comment: Since $C$ is a subset of $B$, $A \cap B \cap C = A \cap C$. $B$ and $C$ are not independent. Besides, $A \cup B \cup C = A \cup B$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need any fancy formula like that. If $C\subseteq B$, then $B\cup C=B$, and $A\cup B\cup C= A\cup B$. Therefore, you only have to compute $P(A\cup B)$.

(You can use your formula for this one, but $A$ and $B$ are already independent, therefore...)